# Web Chatting Application in Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, chat

Is it possible to create a web-chatting application using java Applet ??

As far as I know, using Java Applet we cannot access Web Server due to Sandbox restriction.
But I'm not very sure about this ..

Comment: yes it is possible to do

Comment: in that case, there won't be any security related issues like accessing something out of sandbox ??

Comment: please check [this](http://mathsrv.ku-eichstaett.de/MGF/homes/grothmann/java/chat/) I haven't checked but it seems what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sand-boxed applet can 'phone home' to its own server with no problems.  It is only accessing other servers that requires trust.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I remember we can access server from which we downloaded this applet without problems. Another opportunity is to try to sign the code to make it trusted.

Comment: But applets are loaded on local pc before actually getting executed.